# Integration with respect to a concrete measure

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

I got the problem of integrating with respect to a measure in concrete detail. Im just finding formal stuff elsewhere.
The measure $Q(A)=\int_0^\infty P(f(r,X)\in A)dr$ is given and i need to show that
$\int_{||x||<1} ||x||^2 Q(dx)<\infty$. Is it possible to rewrite the latter integral in doing something with Q? So i dont have to integrate with repsect to Q or how do i do it.

Btw in my problem f is given to me, but it is unnecessary to my problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If $f$ is borel and non-decreasing for every $r$, then $P(f(r,X) \in A) = F_X (f^{-1}(r,A))$ (or integral is taken over a set $I_{f,r}(A)=\{x: f(r,x) \in A\}$). Thus in this case $Q(A)=\int_0^{\infty} \int_{f^{-1}(r,A)}dF_X(x)dr$. If $X$ has a density and $f$ is differentiable and monotonic, integrals can be written using densities.

Comment: Sorry, I understand the problem of finding the analytical expression and I'll try to think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definiton of $Q$ can be rewritten as $$Q(A) = \int \int_0^{\infty} 1_A(f(r,X)) \, dr \, d\mathbb{P}.$$ This means that for any step function of the form $$g(x) := \sum_{j=1}^n c_j 1_{A_j}(x)$$ (here $c_j \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants and $A_j$ measurable sets for $j=1,\ldots,n$), we have

$$\int g(x) \, Q(dx) = \int \int_0^{\infty} g(f(r,X)) \, dr \, d\mathbb{P}.$$ This identity does actually not only hold for step functions, but for any measurable function $g$ such that the left-hand side is well-defined. Applying this with $g(x) := |x|^2 1_{|x| <1}$ gives

$$\int_{|x|<1} |x|^2 \, Q(dx) = \int \int |f(r,X)|^2 1_{|f(r,X)| < 1} \, dr \, d\mathbb{P}.$$